# Android Creating Views Programmatically not getting separated instances

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < cantcuenta ; i++) {
        textview = new ArrayList<>();
        final Integer nro = i + 1;
        Hmayor = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        param.weight = pesoLayout;
        Hmayor.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Hmayor.setWeightSum(1);
        Hmayor.setLayoutParams(param);

        scrollview = new ScrollView(view.getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
        params.weight = 0.65f;
        scrollview.setLayoutParams(params);

        linearinterno = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
        linearinterno.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearinterno.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrollview.addView(linearinterno);


        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            test = new TextView(view.getContext());
            test.setId(j);
            test.setText("Lorem Ipsum" + j);
            test.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textview.add(test);
        }

        boleta = new Button(view.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parambo = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);
        boleta.setLayoutParams(parambo);
        boleta.setText("BOLETA");
        boleta.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        boleta.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        boleta.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        boleta.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(white, null));
        boleta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorAccent, null));
        boleta.setId(nro);
        boleta.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        boleta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boleta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        factura = new Button(view.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramfa = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);
        paramfa.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, boleta.getId());
        factura.setLayoutParams(paramfa);
        factura.setText("FACTURA");
        factura.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        factura.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        factura.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        factura.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(white, null));
        factura.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorAccent, null));
        factura.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        factura.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        factura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });



        ncuenta = new Button(view.getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramb = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
        paramb.weight = 0.15f;
        ncuenta.setLayoutParams(paramb);
        ncuenta.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        ncuenta.setText("CUENTA " + nro);
        ncuenta.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        ncuenta.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        ncuenta.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
        ncuenta.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(letras, null));
        ncuenta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(transparent, null));
        ncuenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Boolean sw = false;

                for (TextView este : textview)
                {
                    if (este.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    {
                        este.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearinterno.addView(este);
                        factura.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        boleta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sw = true;
                    }

                }

                if (!sw)
                {
                    for (TextView este : textview)
                    {
                        este.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        factura.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        boleta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    linearinterno.removeAllViews();
                }
            }
        });
        Hmayor.addView(ncuenta);
        Hmayor.addView(scrollview);

        linearinternodw = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramdw = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
        paramdw.weight = 0.2f;
        linearinternodw.setLayoutParams(paramdw);
        
        Hmayor.addView(linearinternodw);


        relainterno = new RelativeLayout(view.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramr = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relainterno.setLayoutParams(paramr);
        
        relainterno.addView(factura);
        relainterno.addView(boleta);

        linearinternodw.addView(relainterno);

        theParent.addView(Hmayor);
    }
```

it creates this distribution

[image]

when I press the button "CUENTA 1" with the name "ncuenta" in the code it should make all the text in the its own layout gone along with the buttons "BOLETA" and "FACTURA" also shown in the picture but instead, it makes it gone for the "CUENTA 2" views, I have done this kind of coding for recyclerviews and everything get instanced separately, would think that with a FOR every time it does create a new instance of any view it would get attached to the corresponding cycle of the FOR.

if I divide the screen in 4 the first 3 buttons will show and hide the "CUENTA 4" which tells me the the setOnclickListener its only taking the last set of items instanced..

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onClickListener` executes this code

```
for (TextView este : textview)
                {
                    if (este.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    {
                        este.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearinterno.addView(este);
                        factura.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        boleta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sw = true;
                    }

                }
```

When executed, the contents of the textview `ArrayList` will be the elements you add in the last iteration, that's why only the views in the last section are targeted. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: yes thats what I dont get.. the onClickListener is specific for each button as they get new instances for each iteration.. as I said i have done the same thing for recyclerviews and works perfectly.. why would it be different now?, theres is a NEW instance of the textview arraylist for every cycle of the FOR for every button created. the arraylist for "CUENTA 1" is different from the arraylist of "CUENTA 2"

Comment: The listener is specific for each button, but when it executes the ArrayList content is always the same. I don't know how you implemented your RecyclerView, but in this case its behavior is the expected one.

Comment: Ok so the previous instances of the array Gets destroyed

Comment: They don't get destroyed, but you are losing the references to them.

Comment: Another way would be to retrieve the TextViews dynamicaly. By calling `v.getParent()` you will get the current button parent, then you should search within its children structure using the methods `getChildCount()`  and `getChildAt()`.